# Remove constraint and table name version details in sql developer data model

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-modeling

I have problem with Table and Constraint name ,which are coming with version in Model Diagram representation.Using *Oracle SQL Developer Data Modle*  shows my table name as  **APP_REALm_ENTRIESv4**,but my table name used in create statement is **APP_REALm_ENTRIES** .Table name comes with extra characters **v4**.Because that no of time I have re-created table is four.Same problem persists with contraints too like **ARE_ID_PK** added with **v4**.

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but in any case you shouldn't create your own objects under `SYSTEM`.

Comment: `SYSTEM` should be used to administer the database and not for general database purpose.

Comment: Please check I have updated the question.

Comment: open the properties by double-clicking on the table in the diagram - can you not change the name there?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith thanks for reply but it's not reflecting in model even if I update there.

Comment: can you post your question to our OTN Community? We can go into more depth there https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/sql_developer_data_modeler

Answer (score 1):

When the modeler adds "v1" or "v2" or .. on your table name your chosen table name is already defined in your model and your edited table should get the same name. To avoid that conflict the modeler adds "v1".